# Regex: substitute spaces after specific word

Tags: regex, replace, sas, pcre

I’m trying (and failing) to write a regular expression (PCRE2) which will replace every space with a dash (-) after the first instance of a particular word (namely •VAN•, •VON• or •DE•) which itself must be surrounded by spaces.

For example:

```
HENRIETTA VON DER GRAAF
CAROLINE VAN OOSTEN DE WINKEL
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
ANNEKA VANHOVEN BAKKER
JOHN WILKINSON SMITH
```

would translate to:

```
HENRIETTA VON-DER-GRAAF
CAROLINE VAN-OOSTEN-DE-WINKEL
MARC DE-VRIES-VAN-JONG
ANNEKA VANHOVEN BAKKER (NB: Does not match VAN as not surrounded by spaces)
JOHN WILKINSON SMITH (NB: No substitution here as pattern not matched)
```

This is as far as I’ve got, but it’s not substituting all of the spaces following the match:

```
\b( VON| VAN| DE)+\s
```

https://regex101.com/r/s6BC1y/1

Any advice most appreciated!

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Which spaces isn't it substituting?

Comment: Why does your desired result have `-` after `OOSTEN` and `VRIES`? That's not one of the words you want to match.

Comment: Why do you have `+` after the capture group? That will match multiple sequential occurrences of the words, and replace them with just the last one.

Comment: Essentially, if it finds •VAN•, •VON• or •DE•, I want it to substitute every space thereafter for a dash (including the space after VAN, VON or DE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your transformation without regular expressions.

```
data have;
input text $CHAR50.;
datalines;
HENRIETTA VON DER GRAAF
CAROLINE VAN OOSTEN DE WINKEL
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
ANNEKA VANHOVEN BAKKER
JOHN WILKINSON SMITH
;

data want;
  set have;
  p = prxmatch('m/\b(VAN|VON|DE)( )/',text);
  if 0 < p < length(text) then 
    substr(text,p+1) = translate(substr(trim(text),p+1),'-',' ');
run;
```

[image]

Comment: "You can do your transformation without regular expressions" and using `prxmatch` confuses me.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `\G` and `\K`:

```
(?:                # Match either
  (?<!\S)          #                      but only if it is not preceded by a whitespace,
  (?:VON|VAN|DE)   # 'VON', 'VAN' or 'DE'
|                  # or
  \G(?!\A)         # the end of the last match
  \S+              # then a sequence of non-whitespace characters.
)                  # 
\K\x20             # Forfeit everything we just match, then match a space.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VzPr5p/1).

Due to the lack of support for non-fixed-width lookbehinds in PCRE2, we can't do something like the following, which is arguably easier to understand:

```
(?<=               # Match a position preceded by
  (?:VON|VAN|DE)   # either of the three words
  (?:\x20\S+)*     # then 0 or more (space + word),
)                  # 
\x20               # and a space at that position.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VzPr5p/2).

[`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) matches the position at the end of the last match *or* the start of the entire string. Thanks to `(?!\A)`, the latter alternative will only match once we matched the first alternative: `(?<!\S)(?:VON|VAN|DE)`.

A visual explanation:

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
     ^ Start matching `(?<!\S)(?:VON|VAN|DE)`
```

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
       ^ ...then `\x20`.
```

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
        ^ `(?<!\S)(?:VON|VAN|DE)` doesn't match here; switch to `\S+`
```

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
             ^ `\x20` is matched.
```

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
              ^ Back to step 1.
```

```
MARC DE VRIES VAN JONG
                  ^ Back to step 3.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the result you want using this regex:

```
^(.*? (?:VAN|VON|DE)) |((?<!^)\G\w+)
```

This matches either:

- `^(.*? (?:VAN|VON|DE))`  : some minimal number of characters after beginning of line, followed by a space, and one of `VON`, `VAN` or `DE`, all captured in group 1, then a space; or
- `((?<!^)\G\w+)`  : some number of word characters starting at the end of the last successful match (but not at the beginning of string, which `\G` normally allows), captured in group 2, then a space

You can then replace the matches with `$1$2-` (only one of `$1` or `$2` will have any content).

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sYPX3w/1)

Note that the regex can be simplified using `\K` to discard the first parts of the match and only match the space after the words:

```
^.*? (?:VAN|VON|DE)\K |(?<!^)\G\w+\K
```

Then the substitution is simply `-`.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eLVS3b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -anE '
    if (/\b(?:VON|VAN|DE)\b/) {
        @a = split /\s+/;
        say $a[0], " ", join "_", @a[1..$#a]
    } else {
        print;
    }
' file
```

```
HENRIETTA VON_DER_GRAAF
CAROLINE VAN_OOSTEN_DE_WINKEL
MARC DE_VRIES_VAN_JONG
ANNEKA VANHOVEN BAKKER
JOHN SMITH
```